# Execution explanantion

Tags: c++

When we assign a pointer to a variable we are tend to use the '&' operator as in :
   
    `int a = 10;
    int *aa = &a;`

If not used it gives error. But I came across this code where pointer is assigned to array arr but '&' isn't used

```cpp
    int arr[10];
    int *a = &arr;
```

and on using it shows the error:
cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int*' in initialization.

Comment: _" why `&arr` is not used?"_ What do you mean? Post a [mcve] including the input, actual output and expected output please.

Comment: Also see [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

Answer (score 1):

As the link @πάντα ῥεῖ shared will tell you, C style arrays decay into a pointer to the first element in the array, so when sending such an array to **any** function, it needs to be accompanied with the size of the array or else the function will not now its size (unless provided by other means). The streaming operators, `operator<<` and `operator>>` are just functions that take one argument, so

```
std::cin >> arr;
```

will try to find a function with the signature:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, int*);
```